# How do you loop over each div within a container that has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs that have the class of 'flag-container'. My goal is to (using jquery) loop over each of these divs, find the image within it (each div has a single child image) and then return the ID of that image. How would I be able to achieve this and loop over these divs one by one? (I'm not very good with JS loops)

Comment: Try this: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Why would you need to retrieve the ID of these images? You'd have better to explain your expected final behaviour and provide all relevant code in question itself

Comment: There is no relevant code, hence why I asked the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `each()`

```
$( ".flag-container" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log($(this).find('img').attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: I think this is `//do your stuff` part the important part?!

Comment: @A.Wolff he said he is not good with loops  and I show him how to loop. he knows what he wants I don't have to write every code for him that make him lazy :)

Comment: Thank you, it was actually the loop I was interested in. I just mentioned the images to let people know why I want the loop.

Comment: welcome :) .. and always post clear questions only then you will get the right answer other wise people don't give any answer and will down vote your question

Answer (score 5):

Try this out:

```
$('div.flag-container > img').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

As mentioned in the comments and in @Stewartside's answer, the above selector will only work if the `img` is a direct descendent of your `flag-container` div.

If not, you should use the more general selector `$('div.flag-container img')`.

You could also do

```
$('div.flag-container').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('img').attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: This at least answer the question. FYI, `$(this).attr('id')` is just more 'boring' way to write `this.id` :)

Comment: I don't know whether by _each div has a single child image_ OP means that `img` is direct child of `div`, but it's your choice. What I really want to say is that `this.id` looks a liitle shorter `$(this).attr('id')`, so why not to use it?

Comment: Yeah, without knowing the OP's markup, `div.flag-container img` would be the more reliable selector.

Comment: agree with all the points, updated the answer. `$(this).attr('id')` is just the way I write it out of habit more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery's `each()` function.

```
$('div.flag-container img').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Read more here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle for your answer : http://jsfiddle.net/rLbkyeha/

```
$(".flag-container").each(function(){
   alert( $(this).children('img').attr('id'));
});
```